# Show that the distinct cosets form a partition

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Y$ be a subspace of a vector space $X$. A coset is the set  $x+Y=\{v\mid v=x+y, y\in Y\}$.

Here is my attempt at proof that the the distinct cosets form a partition of $X$:

Proof: Let $Y$ be a subspace of a vector space $X$. Let $v,x,x'\in X$ be such that $x\ne x'$. Suppose $v\in x+Y$ and $v\in x' +Y$. Then there exists $y,y'\in Y$ such that $v= x+y$ and $v=x'+y'$. So $x+y=x'+y'$...

I'm trying to show that this leads to a contradiction, but I am stuck. There are other examples on stack, but none of them use the method I am trying to use. Am I going the wrong direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From where you left

$$x+y=x'+y' \iff x-x'=y'-y \in Y$$

But then $x=x'+y_0 \implies x+Y=x'+Y$

A nicer approach, I think, is to show that $u \sim v \iff u - v \in Y$ yields an equivalence relationship.